# Apply DRY to a dict where data is coming from different vars

Tags: python, django

I have two functions where I pass the dict `event_data = {[...]}` to the Google API.
The only difference is that for `update_calendar_event` the data is coming from a `dict`.
For `create_calendar_event` it is an `obj`.

Do you have any idea how to apply DRY here while considering that it's these two different types?

```
class GoogleCalendarAPI:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # cache_discovery=False to avoid ImportError
        self.service = build(
            "calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False
        )

    def _event_link(self, event_slug: str) -> str:
        return "https://example.com/events/" + event_slug

    def update_calendar_event(
        self, calendar_event_id: str, validated_data: Dict[str, Any], event_slug: str
    ) -> None:
        event_data = {
            "summary": validated_data.get("name"),
            "description": validated_data.get("description")
            + "\n\nEvent link: "
            + self._event_link(event_slug),
            "start": {
                "dateTime": validated_data.get("start_date").isoformat(),
                "timeZone": validated_data.get("timezone"),
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": validated_data.get("end_date").isoformat(),
                "timeZone": validated_data.get("timezone"),
            },
        }
        self.service.events().patch(
            calendarId=CALENDAR_ID, eventId=calendar_event_id, body=event_data
        ).execute()

    def create_calendar_event(self, event_instance) -> str:
        event_data = {
            "summary": event_instance.name,
            "description": event_instance.description
            + "\n\nEvent link: "
            + self._event_link(event_instance.slug),
            "start": {
                "dateTime": event_instance.start_date.isoformat(),
                "timeZone": event_instance.timezone,
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": event_instance.end_date.isoformat(),
                "timeZone": event_instance.timezone,
            },
        }
        event = (
            self.service.events()
            .insert(calendarId=CALENDAR_ID, body=event_data)
            .execute()
        )
        return event.get("id")
```

Comment: You can create a piece of code that migrates either the object to dict, or dict to the object, and work with the one you prefer in your code

Comment: Actually just found that `vars(obj)` is exactly doing that. :)